# Question about drupal_add_js

Tags: javascript

I used `drupal_add_js()` to add a jquery plugin, but there is an error `TypeError: $ is undefined` at console of firebug. So how should I add the js?

Comment: try replacing the $ with jQuery tag. Something like `jQuery('#some-id').hide();` instead of `$('#some-id').hide();` and we can carry on from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd find [this article](https://drupal.org/node/171213) in the Drupal documentation relevant and helpful.

The solution is to wrap your custom Javascript code within a closure as shown below:

```
(function($) {
  // Your Javascript code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

Javascript files from all Drupal core modules follow this convention. So, you can look them up for reference.

I'm not really sure but either before/after some version of jQuery, the `$` was a global alias for the jQuery object itself and could be used directly without the closure but was later removed as it conflicted with other libraries.

Comment: It is the problem of third part library, it used `$` without the closure.